# Sorting two dimensional array by date

Tags: asp-classic

I have a two dimensional array. One dimension is date, other dimension is name.

And I am trying to sort these array values by the latest date.

I looked at couple of examples and I came up with this.

But dates are not sorted properly.

```
    DataMax = uBound(sDateArray)-1

For i = 0 to DataMax
    For j = i + 1 to DataMax 
        If DateDiff("s", DataArray(j, 0), DataArray(i, 0)) > 0 Then
            TemporalVariable    =   sDateArray(i, 0)
            sDateArray(i, 0)        =   sDateArray(j, 0)
            sDateArray(j, 0)        =   TemporalVariable
        End If
    Next 
Next


    For i=0 to DataMax
      Response.write (sDateArray(i) & "<BR>") 
    next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found one online example.
Its not a function, its a sub but it works fine.
Other suggestions always welcome.

```
Sub DataSorter(arrArray)
    Dim row, j, StartingKeyValue, StartingOtherValue, _
        NewStartingKey, NewStartingOther, _
        swap_pos

    For row = 0 To UBound(arrArray)-1
        StartingKeyValue = arrArray(row, 0)
        StartingOtherValue = arrArray(row, 0)
        NewStartingKey = arrArray(row, 0)
        NewStartingOther = arrArray(row, 0)
        swap_pos = row
        For j = row + 1 to UBound(arrArray)
            If arrArray(j, 0) > NewStartingKey Then
                swap_pos = j
                NewStartingKey = arrArray(j, 0)
                NewStartingOther = arrArray(j, 0)
            End If
        Next    
        If swap_pos <> row Then
            arrArray (swap_pos, 0) = StartingKeyValue
            arrArray (swap_pos, 0) = StartingOtherValue            
            arrArray (row, 0) = NewStartingKey
            arrArray (row, 0) = NewStartingOther     
        End If  
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

this article shows a sorting in classic ASP: https://web.archive.org/web/20190717135528/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/062701-1.shtml

in summary, this is the sorting part (just replace the string comparison with your date comparison):

```
Sub SortArray(aTempArray) 
  Dim iTemp, jTemp, strTemp

  For iTemp = 0 To UBound(aTempArray)  
    For jTemp = 0 To iTemp  

      If strComp(aTempArray(jTemp), aTempArray(iTemp)) > 0 Then
        'Swap the array positions
        strTemp = aTempArray(jTemp) 
        aTempArray(jTemp) = aTempArray(iTemp) 
        aTempArray(iTemp) = strTemp 
      End If 

    Next 
  Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: this is very similar to what I have here.

Comment: yes, but if you notice, the loops start and end in different indexes.  Try those changes and see if the sort works now

Answer (score -1):

That loop is not a correct sorting algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm